# MNIST data processing - PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to code a Variational Autoencoder for MNIST dataset and the data pre-processing is as follows:

```
# Create transformations to be applied to dataset-
transforms = torchvision.transforms.Compose(
    [
        torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
        torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
        (0.1307,), (0.3081,)
        # (0.5,), (0.5,)
        )
    ]
)


# Create training and validation datasets-
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    # root = 'data', train = True,
    root = path_to_data, train = True,
    download = True, transform = transforms
    )

val_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    # root = 'data', train = False,
    root = path_to_data, train = False,
    download = True, transform = transforms
    )

# Sanity check-
len(train_dataset), len(val_dataset)
# (60000, 10000)

# Create training and validation data loaders-
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset = train_dataset, batch_size = 32,
    shuffle = True,
    # num_workers = 2
    )

val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset = val_dataset, batch_size = 32,
    shuffle = True,
    # num_workers = 2
    )

# Get a mini-batch of train data loaders-
imgs, labels = next(iter(train_dataloader))

imgs.shape, labels.shape
# (torch.Size([32, 1, 28, 28]), torch.Size([32]))

# Minimum & maximum pixel values-
imgs.min(), imgs.max()
# (tensor(-0.4242), tensor(2.8215))

# Compute min and max for train dataloader-
min_mnist, max_mnist = 0.0, 0.0

for img, _ in train_dataloader:
    if img.min() < min_mnist:
        min_mnist = img.min()
    if img.max() > max_mnist:
        max_mnist = img.max()

print(f"MNIST - train: min pixel value = {min_mnist:.4f} & max pixel value = {max_mnist:.4f}")
# MNIST - train: min pixel value = -0.4242 & max pixel value = 2.8215

min_mnist, max_mnist = 0.0, 0.0

for img, _ in val_dataloader:
    if img.min() < min_mnist:
        min_mnist = img.min()
    if img.max() > max_mnist:
        max_mnist = img.max()

print(f"MNIST - validation: min pixel value = {min_mnist:.4f} & max pixel value = {max_mnist:.4f}")
# MNIST - validation: min pixel value = -0.4242 & max pixel value = 2.8215
```

Using 'ToTensor()' and 'Normalize()' transforms, the output image pixels are in the range [-0.4242, 2.8215]. The output layer of the decoder within the VAE either uses the sigmoid or tanh activation function. Sigmoid outputs values in the range [0, 1], while tanh outputs values in the range[-1, 1].

This can be a problem since the input is in the range  [-0.4242, 2.8215], while the output can be in the range [0, 1] or [-1, 1] depending on the activation being used - sigmoid or tanh.

The reconstruction loss being used is MSE. BCE could also be used but it is suggested for Bernoulli distributions vs. continuous data - pixel values.

One simple fix is to just use 'ToTensor()' transformation which scales the input in the range [0, 1] and then use sigmoid activation function for the output decoder layer within the VAE. But what's a better approach for data pre-processing using images which need normalization with 'Normalize()' transformation for each of the channels such that the input and output/reconstructions are in the same range?

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi MSE loss.

Comment: based on experience, normalizing the inputs to be from [0, 1] and applying a tanh activation in the last layer tends to give good results.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to remove the sigmoid or tanh activation function in the last layer and just use a Linear layer as your output. In that case, the network can output any value and is not restricted to [0,1] or [-1, 1].

Comment: For a VAE, it's generally advisable to use a sigmoid or tanh as the activation function for the decoder's last layer.